# Mouse freezing/lagging when hit breakpoint

Tags: wpf, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, mousekeyhook

Goal: To be able to find point(X,Y) of element on windows desktop application which been clicked without performing click itself.

Not working solution
I've added [mousekeyhook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) Nuget package to my .net core WPF application, it working fine ( when click and event raising with correct position), but each time that program hit breakpoint( for specific below example - at M_Events_MouseDown method)  the mouse starts to lag for about 20 seconds.

**Also i have found that in WinForms application it works smoothly**

MouseKeyHook implementation:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_Events;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SubscribeGlobal();
        }

        private void SubscribeGlobal()
        {
            Unsubscribe();
            Subscribe(Hook.GlobalEvents());
        }

        private void Subscribe(IKeyboardMouseEvents events)
        {
            m_Events = events;
            m_Events.MouseDown += M_Events_MouseDown; 
        }

        private void M_Events_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Mouse down :{e}");
        }

        private void Unsubscribe()
        {
            if (m_Events == null)
                return;

            m_Events.MouseDown -= M_Events_MouseDown;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and low-level hook behavior by design.

When you hook into the mouse event processing chain, your code is one of many other processors. Every hooked piece of code has a possibility to suppress or modify further processing. Nevertheless, there is a time limit to do so. If you set a breakpoint, windows call your code, your code does not respond, a timeout occurs and it starts over.

See a similar question for details. The second answer with more upvotes is the better one.: [Low level mouse hook - mouse freeze on breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130167/low-level-mouse-hook-mouse-freeze-on-breakpoint)

Comment: Thanks George for your answer, can you explain why in WinForms application it works smoothly ( no lagging/freezing of mouse), is there an alternative way to capture mouse coordinates on click?